# Get TkInter to display user input?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am fairly new to TkInter and GUI in python (but I have experience with python in general). I was working on a GUI in TkInter and want to have users enter their name and have TkInter display there name when they click the button. Here is my code so far:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

e = Entry(master)
e.pack()

e.focus_set()

def callback():
    print e.get() 

b = Button(master, text="get", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()

separator = Frame(height=2, bd=1, relief=SUNKEN)
separator.pack(fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)

Label(text=callback).pack()

mainloop()
```

Users will enter their name in the `Entry` (or `e`) and I want to display `e` in the label widget. Any ideas on how I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

At the top (below the imports), define `name` as a `StringVar`:

```
name = StringVar()
```

In the function `callback` change the content to be:

```
def callback():
    name.set(e.get())
```

And finally, change your `Label` widget to:

```
Label(master, textvariable=name)
```

So what I have done is created a special object with which when we change its value, the value of all references to it will change also. We can then set our function to change the value to update it globally- and we finish by utilizing this capability by putting this variable as the text attribute in our `Label`.

*Note*: I also added the parent argument to your `Label`. Without it, it wouldn't show up at all.

Comment: `text` in Label should be `textvariable` when using StringVars.  Otherwise a good answer.